# Calculate dataframe mean by skipping certain values in Python / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan, mean

I need to calculate the mean of the first column of the dataframe and I can do that using the `mean()` method. 
The problem: Sometimes, there are -9999 values in the data denoting missing observations. 
I know that NaN values are inherently skipped when calculating the mean in Pandas, but this is not the case with -9999 values of course.

Here is the code I tried. It calculates the mean of the column, but by taking the -9999 value into the calculations:

```
df=pandas.DataFrame([{2,4,6},{1,-9999,3}])
df[0].mean(skipna=-9999)
```

but it yields a mean value of -4998.5 which obviously is produced taking the -9999 into the calculations.

Comment: Sorry you've not given the columns any names so are you wanting the mean of the column or row

Comment: Ok. Edited the question by explicitly mentioning "columns"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `skipna` arg is a boolean specifying whether or not to exclude NA/null values, not which values to ignore:

```
skipna : boolean, default True
    Exclude NA/null values. If an entire row/column is NA, the result
    will be NA
```

Assuming I understand what you're trying to do, you could replace `-9999` by `NaN`:

```
In [41]: df[0].replace(-9999, np.nan)
Out[41]: 
0     2
1   NaN
Name: 0, dtype: float64

In [42]: df[0].replace(-9999, np.nan).mean()
Out[42]: 2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

`skipna` is a meant to be true or false, not a value to be skipped.

when reading your data, normalize, and replace -9999 with n/a.